# How can i get & Store all Pancakeswap chart deta?

Tags: uniswap, decentralized-exchange, price

I want to create my own dex! Not forking, in smart contract i added some new system,so now i want to know how can i store chart deta and show this on Front, Daily / monthly  chart anyone have idea how can i achieve this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: For your app you could index the data in a database. TheGraph might work for you.